# will the memory overflow if python processing too many bigtext

Tags: python, string, memory

python will store all strings in athene_pool and will never release them,so bigtext prcocessing bothered me recently.
I save article contents to redis,and fetch them from redisclient,and send them to http response.while serialization may will cause too much memory,is there any good idea to resolve  things like this?
I wonder if django generated too many responses,how it releases them to keep memory low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not pool all strings, see [Are strings pooled in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519580/are-strings-pooled-in-python).

For example, this 10K string is not pooled:

```
>>> a = '5' * 10000
>>> b = '5' * 10000
>>> a is b
False
```

But a short 5 character string *is* pooled:

```
>>> a = '5' * 5
>>> b = '5' * 5
>>> a is b
True
```

Ergo: you don't need to worry about long strings being kept in memory longer than necessary.

Comment: About the 'is' test: the python 'is' operator tests if two objects are really the same object. In this case I'm abusing the operator to check if two strings got merged into one string.

Comment: Even short strings are only pooled if they occur as string literals in the source code (or are explicitly interned via some function `sys` IIRC). The compiler constant-folds the `5` * 5` in your snippet into `'55555'` as you'll see if you put it into a function and run `dis.dis` over it.