# Python are strings immutable

Tags: python

If a python string is immutable, how can it be changed as follows:

```
  a = "abc"
  print a
  a = "cde"
  print a
```

Outputs:

```
abc
cde
```

Is this actually creating a new variable and changed a to point to that instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python strings *are* immutable. What you're doing is just reassigning the `a` variable with two different strings, that has nothing to do with immutability.

In the code shown no new variables are being created, there's just `a`. And in the assignments, `a` is pointed to a different string each time. To see that strings are immutable, take a look at this example:

```
a = 'abxde'
b = a.replace('x', 'c')

a
=> 'abxde'

b
=> 'abcde'
```

As you can see, `a` was not modified by the `replace()` method, instead that method created a new string, which we assigned to `b`, and that's where the replaced string ended. All string methods that perform changes are just like that: they don't modify the original string in-place, they create and return a new one.

Comment: I agree my understanding is in the wrong here - i am trying to learn though.  How can i prove that the string is immutable in code

Comment: Ok thanks - that now makes sense.  Does the garbage collector pick up any old references after a was assigned to another string?

Comment: It's possible, it depends on the implementation (whether it pools strings or not). Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2519616/201359).

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, in Python, strings are immutable
- Your code is not creating a new variable
- Your code assigns the variable `a` a reference to another string

Answer (score 1):

It's creating a new object and changing `a` to point to the new object.