# Why do Python built-ins interact differently with the "is" keyword?

Tags: python

Here is something odd that I came across while experimenting with the 'is' keyword. When I use Python built-ins to create identical objects, Python assigns the same id to them:

```
>>> a = str()
>>> b = str()
>>> id(a), id(b)
(29857888 29857888)
>>> a is b
True
```

Creating the string explicitly works the same way:

```
>>> a = ''
>>> b = ''
>>> id(a), id(b)
(29857888 29857888)
>>> a is b
True
```

However, when I make my own classes, Python assigns different ids.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...    pass
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> d = MyClass()
>>> id(c), id(d)
(16566256 16566800)
>>> c is d
False
```

How/why does Python do this? Is there a way to implement this "id matching" functionality for my own classes?

Comment: Small immutable objects may be cached, depending on the implementation. `c` and `d` are not the same object, so `c is d` is `False`.

Comment: It's not about assigning IDs. Two objects alive at the same time never have the same ID. It's about *returning the same object*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519580/are-strings-pooled-in-python

Comment: If you want to do this with your own class, check out [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).