# Python id issues

Tags: python, python-internals

I was playing with the following codes and found out that the string variables have same ids.
Can anyone please tell me why only string acts differently unlike other two int and list type?

To sum up the question again, the number1 and number2 have different ids.
list1 and list2 also have different ids. However, string1, string2 and even string3 have same ids with other string variables...!

```
number1 = 123456
number2 = 123456
number3 = number1
print(id(number1))
print(id(number2))
print(id(number3))

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = list1
print(id(list1))
print(id(list2))
print(id(list3))

string1 = 'hello'
string2 = 'hello'
string3 = string1
print(id(string1))
print(id(string2))
print(id(string3))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are strings pooled in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519580/are-strings-pooled-in-python)

Comment: Don't make any assumptions about the id of an object produced by a literal. It's up to the Python implementation whether to reuse a pre-existing object as the result of evaluating the literal.

Comment: Your distinct lists, like any mutable objects, *must* have distinct IDs - Python would be utterly broken if two different lists suddenly became one, and started seeing each other's changes, just because they were coincidentally equal at some point in time.  But immutable objects can share an ID without any problems, and as a matter of optimization Python will do this in cases where duplicate values are likely.  The specific cases where it's considered worth the effort to check for an existing duplicate value are `int`s in the -5..255 range, and `str`s that look like a valid Python identifier.

Comment: Your 3s will always be the same objects as your 1s because you're defining them that way. Python names act like references, they don't copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've observed some of internal implementation details (optimizations that aren't guaranteed by the language):

- Integers in the range `-5 <= x <= 256` are pre-computed on startup and are reused.
- Strings typed directly in your program `string1 = 'hello'` are interned and reused.

There are also some guaranteed behaviors:

- Assignments such as `string3 = string1` never make copies.
- New mutable objects are never reused: `[1, 2, 3]`.  They have have to be distinct so they can mutate differently over time.
- Singletons such as `None` are instantiated only once and can be reliably compared using object identity: `result is None`.

Hope this provides you with some insights in to the language and its implementation.